# Aspose.Cells using array (Ctrl+Shift+Enter or CSE) formula in conditional formatting

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, aspose

I'm using `Aspose.Cells .NET` and I'm trying to use array formula (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd> or CSE) in conditional formatting expression. Array formula looks like this:

```
=VALUE
    (INDEX('Raw data'!$A$5:$AE$32; 
           MATCH(1;(A5='Raw data'!$A$5:$A$32)*(B5='Raw data'!$B$5:$B$32);0);
           3)
    )
<> VALUE(C5)
```

(Line breaks and spaces for convenience. They are not present in actual formula)

Basically it does the following:

1. Looks for a row in another sheet (Raw data) by two columns `A5='Raw data'` Column A AND `B5 = 'Raw data'` Column B
2. Gets 3-rd column in a row that was found
3. Checks that its value not equal to C5 cell

It works when i place it directly into the cell (with <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd>)
It also works when i create conditional formatting (with it) manually with Ms Excel 2010.

But when I try to apply it though Aspose.Cells it throws exception

> Invalid formula

```
// Add an empty conditional formatting
int index = worksheet.ConditionalFormattings.Add();
FormatConditionCollection fcs = ws.ConditionalFormattings[index];

//Add area for conditional formatting
fcs.AddArea(cellArea);

var condition = String.Format(formulaTemplate, initialDataRange, okpoCellName, initialDataOkpoColumnRange, initialDataColumn, currentCellName);

// Throws here 
// condition = "=VALUE(INDEX('Raw data'!$A$5:$AE$32;MATCH(1;(A5='Raw data'!$A$5:$A$32)*(B5='Raw data'!$B$5:$B$32);0);3)) <> VALUE(C5)"
int conditionIndex = fcs.AddCondition(FormatConditionType.Expression, OperatorType.None, condition, "");
```

I suspect that when I add condition, Aspose tries to evaluate it as usual formula (not array formula) and fails. Is there any way to disable/postpone this evaluation?
Is this a bug in Aspose, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Well, Aspose.Cells might not support array formulas in conditional formattings. We recommend you to kindly post your issue/requirements into [Aspose.Cells forums](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx). Give us complete details and complete sample code with your expected Excel file which can be created by MS Excel manually. We can better help you there.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.